# Is there a built in stack implementation in Swift?

Tags: swift, stack

I want to use Stack in my swift code. I couldn't find any inbuilt stack implementation in Swift like java.util.Stack in Java.

I could implement my own Stack in swift but I would prefer a built-in one.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/800-swift-algorithm-club-swift-stack-data-structure

Comment: No, there is no standard Stack in the Swift standard library. You need to write/find your own.

Answer (score 9):

No, but you could implement your own pretty easily

```
struct Stack {
    private var array: [Any] = []

    mutating func push(_ element: Any) {
        array.append(element)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> Any? {
        return array.popLast()
    }

    func peek() -> Any? {
        guard let top = array.last else { return nil }
        return top
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an implementation in the documentation at: 
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html
that is also type agnostic.

```
struct Stack<Element> {
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, Apple has released Swift [Swift Collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections). The Collections package has an implementation of Deque. I can use this as a Stack.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29796041)

Answer (score 0):

**Learned GenericStack with Swift 5.7.1 with Xcode 14:**

**1. First make a Protocol `Stackable` :**

```
protocol Stackable {
            associatedtype ObjectType
            func push(value:ObjectType)
            func pop()
            func peek()->ObjectType?
        }
```

**2. Make a `GenericStack` class using  `Stackable` :**

```
class GenericStack<T>:Stackable {
       private var list:[T] = [T]()
        public var elements:[T]{
            return list
        }
        func push(value: T) {
            list.append(value)
        }
        func pop() {
            if !list.isEmpty {
                list.removeLast()
            }
        }
        func peek() -> T? {
            return list.last
        }
        typealias ObjectType = T
    }
```

**3. Use it with any **Data Type**:**

```
  var stackInt:GenericStack<Int> = GenericStack<Int>()
    print(stackInt.push(value: 5))
    print(stackInt.push(value: 7))
    print(stackInt.elements)
    
    var stackChar:GenericStack<Character> = GenericStack<Character>()
    print(stackChar.push(value: "A"))
    print(stackChar.push(value: "B"))
    print(stackChar.elements)
    var stackString:GenericStack<String> = GenericStack<String>()
    print(stackString.push(value: "Abhi"))
    print(stackString.push(value: "test"))
    print(stackString.elements)
```

Video of execution and learning stack in swift : [XcodePlaygroundWork](https://recordit.co/681rCIZRZ9)